# update an app to the appstore: review time,and rate on the store?

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

This is so frustrating ! 
i have upload our app to the appstore, and after 8 days it was approved ,
then i have download it and discover that the accelerometer is stuck!

so i went to itunes connect,change the release date to a future one, unchecked all the stores in the world, and it says: removed by developer.
thats what i wanted. instead of deleting it.

then after couple of hours:
I found the bug,changed that,upload an update (1.1), and now its in
"waiting for review " again.

questions are:

1. is it take the whole process again? exactly? one more week ?
2. my place in the app store: will it be as i just post a new app? so they will put me in the new apps at the store? (as they did at the first time) ? OR they just put you at the end somewhere ?

i mean- do you get the same opportunity to be IN THE FRONT LINE FOR A WHILE - as a new app (i was at the 10 place of the new releases) ?

**edit :**
the problem is, that i have sent an update to an app that is no longer at the store cause i have unchecked all stores from it, and changed the release date to a future one. so i wonder if in that case i will not be rejected,because its an update for somthing that is not at the store and not avliable for any store in the world!
thats the only way for me to take it off the store and instead of erase it !

thanks a lot .

Comment: Even though you posted basically the same question a couple hours ago and the post was closed, you go back to the bottom of the review queue, and 1.1 will show up in the App Store as a new app.

Comment: @MDT: His former question is different, and frankly I wouldn't have closed it as I think it's a valid development related question IMHO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Yes. The review process will be started from scratch again on your app update.

2) Your app at v1.0 is already live - when you post an update (or a new app altogether) that gets approved, there's a tiny tiny chance it may get selected under the "What's Hot" section of your primary category on the Appstore. It will always appear under the "All   Apps" section too, as an app that was recently released or updated.

Any rank in the charts will be unaffected by the update - but an update tends to boost interest and visibility.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you all but there is something that i dont get. my first app is now in red(rejected by developer) because i disabled all stores, and then i uploaded a binary as an update- but its an update to app the is no longer on the store! now when i got to rights and pricing - i see that all stores are really unchecked,and release date is for a future one-as i put it. but i cant understand if all this information is for the old app or the new one. because i havnt set stores to the new one, and for the old one i disable all of them! i hope its not a problem  ,and i will be rejected for the mess??

Comment: Your old one is totally disabled for now, it seems. Assuming the update gets approved, you have control over when you want to release it. I am not 100% sure on whether you will need to set the stores you want for the approved update, once it reaches that stage. I think your best best for a definite answer to your comment can be gotten from contacting Apple yourself, here: https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php

Comment: I don't believe that the process is completely from scratch, I think that in terms of legality checks about content and the type of app and its usage etc, theses are things that are checked thoroughly for the first time. Updates can be checked more quickly because they are able to see which parts have changed. But I believe it's all the same queue so overall time is not that much shorter.

Comment: Hey Luke, You know what happens in my situation: My app approved and ready for sale, but i have set the date 29.10. If i send a new update(v1.1) will v1.0 still be released 29.10?

Comment: @IbrahimYildirim Hi Ibrahim, I guess that if v1.1 is not approved before 29.10 then v1.0 will go live, and if v1.1 is set by you to go live on 29.10 and it is reviewed and approved before then, then v1.1 would launch. Your best bet is to contact Apple though to seek official clarification on this. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Every time you submit your app to iTunes Connect it has to go through the review process. Yes, even for updates. But often the updates are approved faster, especially if you just state that one or two bugs were fixed. I don't know about the ranking, but I doubt that an update influences it.

Comment: Bug fixes and performance improvements.... its been 7 days now since update of my app is waiting for review.

Comment: @Abhi: That's the [current average review time](http://appreviewtimes.com) right now, so nothing to worry about. But something you need to account for when planing a timed release, of course.