# Updating IOS App. Do updates need to be reviewed?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I've just got an app in the app store and realised theres a spelling mistake on the first view! As the app is intended for an upcoming event occuring in 3 days I am nervous about uploading an update. If I upload new binary to iTunes Connect will that mean my previous version will not be available on the app store? Also, will I need to have Apple approve my latest version prior to releasing it?

Any advice would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553840/update-an-app-to-the-appstore-review-time-and-rate-on-the-store

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you push a new update it has to be reviews but will likely take more than 3 days to do so. While it is waiting to be reviewed your current version will be live.

Comment: OK thanks! So do I just upload the newest version to iTunes Connect, removing the older version's binary? (I'm assuming the code that's actually on the app store is different to the code on iTunes Connect)

Comment: You just add a new binary with a newer version and it'll go through review. When it is approved and you release the new version it will replace what you have. The app you submit to itunes connect becomes what is on the app store but I assume apple adds something to it along the way but I do not know what you mean by that last statement

Comment: Thanks - I meant that if I remove/change the binary in iTunes Connect it wont affect the version that people can purchase in the App Store

Comment: if you remove the current version it will remove it from the app store which is why you don't change the current version but just submit a new one

Comment: You can go on itunesconnect and there will be a list of steps that you can go through to add a new version which is what you want to follow

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, your previous version won't be affected. Just upload the new one, but know that it's gonna take more than 3 days (pretty much always 7, if you submit during work hours). You can file for an expedited review, but even that can sometimes take more than 3 days.

And you don't need to remove the old version to put in the new one. You just submit the new one. You can determine whether you want it to automatically become available on the app store as soon as it's approved, or give it a specific release date.

Just know this: If your update has issues and you're forced to remove it AFTER it has become available on the app store, then you can't just revert back to the old version. You have to resubmit the old version and wait a week for that to get reviewed again.